# Adjoint on $C([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

I am self-studying $C^{*}-$ algebra and the material I read tells me that if $C([0,1])$ represents a set of continuous functions $[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$, then the adjoint on $C([0,1])$ is: $$f\in C([0,1]), f^{*}=\overline{f}$$

I don't get why taking adjoint on $C([0,1])$ is to take the complex conjugate. Any explanation?

Comment: It is a *definition* of an involution on $C[0,1],$ chosen to make it a $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: What @AnneBauval said.  Can you verify that $C[0,1]$ together with that operation is, indeed, a $C^*$-algebra?

Answer (score 1):

> Any explanation?

Here are three rather immediate explanations.

- In a C$^*$-algebra you want elements of the form $f^*f$ to be positive. In $C[0,1]$ you have a natural notion of positivity which is $f\geq0$ if $f(t)\geq0$ for all $t$. So you need $f^*(t)f(t)\geq0$ for all $t$. What recipe can you give me, given a complex number $z$, to choose a number $z^*$ that depends on $z$ and such that it always gives you $z^*z\geq0$? I'm fairly sure you'll come up with $z^*=\overline z$.
- It is typical to see $C[0,1]$ as a subalgebra of $L^\infty[0,1]$ and to implement the latter as multiplication operators on $L^2[0,1]$. That is, there is a (very) natural way to see $C[0,1]$ as bounded linear operators $M_f$ on a Hilbert space, with $\|M_f\|=\|f\|_\infty^{\vphantom f}$. It is then an easy exercise to check that $M_f^{*\vphantom f}=M_{\overline f}$.
- If instead of $C[0,1]$ you consider $C(X)$ for a finite set $X$, you have $C(X)\simeq\mathbb C^{|X|}$ as vector spaces, as algebras, and as $*$-algebras if you consider $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^*=(\overline{x_1},\ldots,\overline{x_n})$, which is the natural adjoint in $\mathbb C^{|X|}$. This corresponds again with $f^*=\overline f$.